# How can I put a function call on a button that pops up a submit form?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I put `fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');` on a button that pops up a submit form?

```html
<form role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
  <div class="fieldset">
    <div class="title">Name*</div>
    <div class="field"><input type="text" id="name" required /></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldset">
    <div class="title">Mobile Number*</div>
    <div class="field"><input type="tel" id="contact" required /></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fieldset">
    <div class="title">E-mail</div>
    <div class="field"><input type="email" id="email" placeholder="(Optional!)" /></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="form-submit" value="Send Now" class="submit" />
  <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify? I do not see any function called `fbq` in your example above.

Comment: Use event delegation:  `$(document).on("click", "button-selector", function() { fbq(...); })`

Comment: thank you so much.  you guys so awesome

Comment: I have a question to ask, why when someone presses a button even if it does not fill out the event form it is still recorded.  How to track event 'CompleteRegistration' only.

Comment: $("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) { fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...